# Fail to call mysqldump from java in linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux, runtime.exec

This is the code :

```
public static File backupDB() throws IOException {

    File file = null;

    file = new File("BKUP_DB_"
            +   Calendar.getInstance()).replace("/", "-") + ".sql");

    String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + "dbUserName" + " -p" + "dbPassword"
    + " " + "dbName" + " > " +file.getPath();



    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {

        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
            runtimeProcess.destroy();
            return file;
        } else {

            System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

    return file;
}
```

i have tried using the full path of mysqldump like `/usr/bin/mysqldum` but nothing seems to be working, i am suspecting permission issues about linux. do you have to be root to be able to create a mysql backup? if not, what is the problem with this code ? if yes what is the problem with linux :D? how can i fix this problem.
thank you.

Comment: What is the exception or error you are getting?

Comment: What does `runtimeProcess.getErrorStream()` or `.exitValue()` tell you?

Comment: there is no exception!  runtimeProcess.waitFor(); returns 6 and i guess that is the sign of mysqldump failing me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The metacharacter ">" is implemented by the shell; no shell is involved in running a program with `Runtime.exec()` so the last two arguments to `mysqldump` are garbage. Use the array argument form of `Runtime.exec()`; pass "/bin/sh" as the first argument, "-c" as the second, and your command line as the third; that way the shell metacharacters will be interpreted by /bin/sh.

Comment: String[] cmdarray = {"/bin/sh","-c",executeCmd};

Comment: @dave: hint: read the tag-wiki of [tag:runtime.exec], it links to a **great** article on this topic (a real must-read).